# how does method updateCredentialsForItem1 work

Tags: yodlee

How does the method ItemManagementService.updateCredentialsForItem1 work?

what happens if I update the account using wrong credential? will it throw exception?

I added one account into yodlee, then I changed the password of that account. It threw error 402 when I tried to get the transactions. After this, I called this method ItemManagementService.updateCredentialsForItem1(userContext, itemId,true, fieldInfoList.ToArray(),true) to update this account. But this method doesn't threw any exception or error code even I updated it using wrong password.

What should I do to make sure yodlee will tell me the credential is wrong if I update the account using wrong credential?

Thanks a lot.
Yuj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe research and experience has told/taught **me that you need to pass false** as the "start refresh on addition/update" and start the refresh manually

The Workflow is exactly the same whether you add or update. 
You add/update:
AddItemForContentService1 (if New) or updateCredentialsForItem1 (if updating credentials).

Then You check if the item can be refreshed and if/when it can Start a refresh and then begin your polling.

You need to check RefreshService.isItemRefreshing (this needs to be false)
Then start the refresh RefreshService.startRefresh7.
Then your standard polling routine which is where you will find out whether the updated credentials worked. Ala, At 10/15 second intervals you need to check the status with RefreshClient.getRefreshInfo passing the content item id.

The return value most notably the RefreshInfo.statusCode which correlates to Gatherer Error codes (see code below) lets you know if there is a problem. 0 is successful.

Below are the C# Enums that I built based upon Java SDK and filling in a few missing values with some tech support. The Values are the same regardless of what language. So it's a good reference as the names semi-make sense.
**402 and 419 are the two most common Login error codes. 402 is invalid credentials, 419 means it didn't register them in time**. The full list of error codes can be found on Yodlee's site here: https://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes.

```
public  enum    GathererErrorsEnum
{
    STATUS_OK = 0,
    STATUS_INVALID_GATHERER_REQUEST = 400,
    STATUS_NO_CONNECTION = 401,
    STATUS_LOGIN_FAILED = 402,
    STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR = 403,
    STATUS_LOST_REQUEST = 404,
    STATUS_ABORT_REQUEST = 405,
    STATUS_PASSWORD_EXPIRED = 406,
    STATUS_ACCOUNT_LOCKED = 407,
    STATUS_DATA_EXPECTED = 408,
    STATUS_SITE_UNAVILABLE = 409,
    STATUS_POP3_SERVER_FAILED = 410,
    STATUS_SITE_OUT_OF_BUSINESS = 411,
    STATUS_SITE_APPLICATION_ERROR = 412,
    STATUS_REQUIRED_FIELD_UNAVAILABLE = 413,
    STATUS_NO_ACCOUNT_FOUND = 414,
    STATUS_SITE_TERMINATED_SESSION = 415,
    STATUS_SITE_SESSION_ALREADY_ESTABLISHED = 416,
    STATUS_DATA_MODEL_NO_SUPPORT = 417,
    STATUS_HTTP_DNS_ERROR = 418,
    STATUS_LOGIN_NOT_COMPLETED = 419,
    STATUS_SITE_MERGED_ERROR = 420,
    STATUS_UNSUPPORTED_LANGUAGE_ERROR = 421,
    STATUS_ACCOUNT_CANCELLED = 422,
    STATUS_ACCT_INFO_UNAVAILABLE = 423,
    STATUS_SITE_DOWN_FOR_MAINTENANCE = 424,
    STATUS_SITE_CERTIFICATE_ERROR = 425,
    STATUS_SITE_BLOCKING_ERROR = 426,
    STATUS_NEW_SPLASH_PAGE = 427,
    STATUS_NEW_TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS = 428,
    STATUS_UPDATE_INFORMATION_ERROR = 429,
    STATUS_SITE_NOT_SUPPORTED = 430,
    STATUS_HTTP_FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR = 431,
    STATUS_HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR = 432,
    STATUS_REGISTRATION_PARTIAL_SUCCESS = 433,
    STATUS_REGISTRATION_FAILED_ERROR = 434,
    STATUS_REGISTRATION_INVALID_DATA = 435,
    STATUS_REGISTRATION_ACCOUNT_ALREADY_REGISTERED = 436,
    STATUS_REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT = 404,
    UNIQUEID_FROM_DATA_SOURCE_ERROR = 475,
    ACCOUNT_REQUIRED_FIELDS_NOT_SET = 476,
    BILL_REQUIRED_FIELDS_NOT_SET = 477,
    STATUS_DUPLICATE_BILL = 478,
    STATUS_COULD_NOT_GENERATE_AUTOREGISTER_CREDENTIALS = 479,
    STATUS_MAX_REGISTRATION_ATTEMPTS_EXCEEDED = 481,
    STATUS_ACCOUNT_REGISTERED_ELSE_WHERE = 484,
    STATUS_REGISTRATION_BOT_SUPPORTED_FOR_REGION = 485,
    STATUS_REGISTRATION_NOT_SUPPORTED_FOR_REGION = 485,
    STATUS_UNSUPPORTED_REGISTRATION_ACCOUNT_TYPE = 486,
    REWARDS_PROGRAM_REQUIRED_FIELDS_NOT_SET = 491,
    REWARDS_ACTIVITY_REQUIRED_FIELDS_NOT_SET = 492,
    TAX_LOT_REQUIRED_FIELDS_NOT_SET = 493,
    INVESTMENT_TRANSACTION_REQUIRED_FIELDS_NOT_SET = 494,
    LOAN_TRANSACTION_REQUIRED_FIELDS_NOT_SET = 495,
    CARD_TRANSACTION_REQUIRED_FIELDS_NOT_SET = 496,
    BANK_TRANSACTION_REQUIRED_FIELDS_NOT_SET = 497,
    HOLDING_REQUIRED_FIELDS_NOT_SET = 498,
    SITE_CURRENTLY_NOT_SUPPORTED = 505,
    NEW_LOGIN_INFO_REQUIRED_FOR_SITE = 506,
    BETA_SITE_WORK_IN_PROGRESS = 507,
    STATUS_INSTANT_REQUEST_TIMEDOUT = 508,
    TOKEN_ID_INVALID = 509,
    PROPERTY_RECORD_NOT_FOUND = 510,
    HOME_VALUE_NOT_FOUND = 511,
    NO_PAYEE_FOUND = 512,
    NO_PAYEE_RETRIEVED = 513,
    SOME_PAYEE_NOT_RETRIEVED = 514,
    NO_PAYMENT_ACCOUNT_FOUND = 515,
    NO_PAYMENT_ACCOUNT_SELECTED = 516,
    GENERAL_EXCEPTION_WHILE_GATHERING_MFA_DATA = 517,
    NEW_MFA_INFO_REQUIRED_FOR_AGENTS = 518,
    MFA_INFO_NOT_PROVIDED_TO_YODLEE_BY_USER_FOR_AGENTS = 519,
    MFA_INFO_MISMATCH_FOR_AGENTS = 520,
    ENROLL_IN_MFA_AT_SITE = 521,
    MFA_INFO_NOT_PROVIDED_IN_REAL_TIME_BY_USER_VIA_APP = 522,
    INVALID_MFA_INFO_IN_REAL_TIME_BY_USER_VIA_APP = 523,
    USER_PROVIDED_REAL_TIME_MFA_DATA_EXPIRED = 524,
    MFA_INFO_NOT_PROVIDED_IN_REAL_TIME_BY_GATHERER = 525,
    INVALID_MFA_INFO_OR_CREDENTIALS = 526,
    STATUS_DBFILER_SUMMARY_SAVE_ERROR = 601,
    STATUS_REQUEST_GENERATION_ERROR = 602,
    STATUS_REQUEST_DISPATCH_ERROR = 603,
    STATUS_REQUEST_GENERATION_ERROR_LOGIN_FAILURE = 604,
    STATUS_REQUEST_GENERATION_ERROR_DELETED_ITEM = 605,
    INPUT_INVALID_DATA = 701,
    INPUT_LENGTH_ERROR = 702,
    INPUT_FORMAT_ERROR = 703,
    INPUT_USERNAME_ALREADY_TAKEN_ERROR = 704,
    INPUT_VALUE_TOO_SMALL = 705,
    INPUT_VALUE_TOO_LARGE = 706,
    REFRESH_NEVER_DONE = 801,
    REFRESH_NEVER_DONE_AFTER_CREDENTIALS_UPDATE     = 802,
}
```

Comment: what's the difference between passing "false" and "true" as the "start refresh on addition/updat"?  if I update with the wrong credential, will the method "RefreshService.startRefresh7" throw exception? In my code, the method "RefreshService.startRefresh7" doesn't throw any exception if I update with wrong credentials.

Comment: the false/true that I'm referring to specifies whether that it should start a refresh automatically. As I said, from the "old Yoldee Developer forums" it was always told to specify false.

Comment: You need to startRefresh7 and then poll (at 5/10/15 second intervals) using getRefreshInfo1. The Return value of getRefreshInfo1 will tell you whether the credentials are invalid. Specifically the RefreshInfo.statusCode . The return value correlates to Gatherer errors.